# Possible dangers of power lines radiation, wi-fi and gsm technology

Tags: electromagnetism, biophysics, medical-physics

I'd like to know more about the topic mentioned in the title. I have 3 questions. I'd be happy to hear your thoughts on any of those.

1. So if high voltage power lines can cause harm to a human in some way, what/how that would be?
   (and I don't mean by touching them causing the current to flow through the body)
   Same question goes for wi-fi and gsm technology.
2. How do we measure those potential dangers of power lines, wi-fi and gsm radiation?
   Is this basically the same or different measurement and quantities?
3. What is the difference between a possibly dangerous field around a power line and a field around a magnet? 
   (what I want to suggest is that this is basically the same kind of field so if one is considered dangerous the then other is also, or am I missing something)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about health issues, which are biological rather than physical.

Comment: so physics go blank? please try to answer anyway.

Comment: Physics doesn't go blank, but interaction of organic tissue with em waves is not what physics is about. The only way to find out reliably what the dangers are is with animal experiments and clinical trials, and that's actually part of medical research.

Comment: yes. i might try on medical forums later. but i guess i still need some background from physics first and so i hope to see some explanations here. regards.

Comment: While asking here seems an obvious choice, there is really very little that physics can do. We can, for instance, characterize tissue heating, but there is no theory that could link a certain level of heating to a health risk (unless the temperature rise is so high that obvious tissue damage occurs, which is not the case with any of the em sources you mentioned). The problem is really that there is no straight forward way to get from physical effects to health risk. If there were, drug companies wouldn't be spending over a billion dollars on a drug trial these days.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about cancers such as leukemia the general consensus in the scientific and medical communities is that to date there is no evidence of increased risk due to exposure to high voltage powerlines, mobile phones or wifi.

The main risks around high voltage power lines are due to high electric field gradients, especially at close vicinity such as adjacent to poles carrying high voltage cables. The danger is referred to as 'step voltage', which is the voltage between a persons feet when standing beneath a powerline. Engineers can calculate this voltage under normal operating conditions and design the powerlines to be high enough to be within safe limits at ground level. Under fault conditions, such as a short circuit, fallen line or lightning strike, the risks are significantly greater.

Most Wifi systems produce electromagnetic radiation in the 2.4GHz or 5 GHz frequency band. The energy levels are quite low and no evidence to date has been produced to prove any increased risk to human health.

Mobile phones emit electromagnetic radiation similar to wifi but at slightly lower frequencies (typically 900MHz or 1800MHz). The energy levels are therefore lower than wifi, although the effect of pressing a mobile phone up against the side of ones head for hours a day is not well understood what risks if any the additional heat might pose on the brain.

Electromagnetic radiation from wifi and mobile phones can be detected with a dipole antenna connected to a suitably tuned electronic amplifier circuit.

High voltage power lines generally transmit electrical power at high voltages and low currents, in order to minimize losses due to joule heating of the lines over long distances. These losses are proportional to the square of the current, so lower currents are preferred to minimize losses. As such, high voltage power lines don't produce high magnetic fields, except during fault conditions such as short circuit ground faults, which are usually interrupted by circuit breakers within a few seconds of the fault.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I don't think there is such a general consensus that you mentioned! I'm afraid it's more like the opposite of what you suggested.

Comment: Type Wi-Fi Dangers - BBC Panorama (1of 2) in Youtube.

Comment: A 2005 scientific study (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15784787) concluded that 'symptoms described by “electromagnetic hypersensitivity” sufferers can be severe and are sometimes disabling. However, it has proved difficult to show under blind conditions that exposure to EMF can trigger these symptoms. This suggests that “electromagnetic hypersensitivity” is unrelated to the presence of EMF, although more research into this phenomenon is required.'

Comment: IARC CLASSIFIES RADIOFREQUENCY ELECTROMAGNETIC FIELDS AS POSSIBLY CARCINOGENIC TO HUMANS Lyon,
France,
May
31,
2011 http://www.iarc.fr/en/media-centre/pr/2011/pdfs/pr208_E.pdf

Comment: @Verbar IARC Group 2B is defined as "limited evidence of carcinogenicity in humans and less than sufficient evidence of carcinogenicity in experimental animals" ([see page 23](http://monographs.iarc.fr/ENG/Preamble/CurrentPreamble.pdf)).  It doesn't mean it causes cancer, it means "keep an eye on this stuff".  Sensational documentaries are not reliable sources.  If you ask a question here and don't get the answer you had in mind, why did you ask in the first place?